# Preencher uma textbox com elemento de uma combobox

Tags: combobox, textbox

Eu tenho uma combobox conectada a um textbox por uma função. Funciona assim: ao passo que a pessoa digita algo na textbox, é automaticamente realizado uma espécie de 'filtro' na combobox, que mostra algo que poderia corresponder ao que a pessoa deseja informar (no caso, uma cidade).

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
<script language="javascript">
    function trocaOpcao(valor, objSel) {
        for (i=0; i < objSel.length; i++){
            qtd = valor.length;
            if (objSel.options[i].text.substring(0, qtd).toUpperCase() == valor.toUpperCase()) {
                objSel.selectedIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<style>
  /*removendo o estilo do select*/
    select {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        text-indent: 1px;
        text-overflow: '';
        border: none;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<form name="form">
<input type="text" name="texto" onkeyup="trocaOpcao(this.value, document.form.cidade);"></br>
<select disabled name="cidade">
    <option selected>Sua Cidade</option>
    <option>sao paulo</option>
    <option>rio de janeiro</option>
    <option>vitoria</option>
    <option>belem</option>
    <option>recife</option>
    <option>santa luzia</option>
    <option>santa cruz</option>
    <option>santarem</option>
</select>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Eu gostaria de saber como preencher o conteúdo da textbox automaticamente com o conteúdo filtrado da combobox ao dar 'enter' ou 'tab'.
Desde já, agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Creio que se eu entendi o jQuery pode lhe atender

```html
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>

<style>
  /*removendo o estilo do select*/
    select {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        text-indent: 1px;
        text-overflow: '';
        border: none;
    }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.14/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form">
<input type="text" id="descricao" />
<input type="hidden" name="idQueVaiParaSeuBackEnd" id="id" />
</form>

<script>
var source = [{
    label: "sao paulo",
    value: "1234"
}, {
    label: "rio de janeiro",
    value: "12321"
}];
/*

Suas cidades devem ser cadastradas no label acima.

*/
$("#descricao").autocomplete({
    source: source,

    //quantidade de caracteres para começar a buscar
    minLength: 3,

    //evento de quando você seleciona uma opção   
    select: function (event, ui) {         

        //seto a descrição para aparecer para usuario no input text
        $("#descricao").val(ui.item.label);

        //seto o id para ir para seu backend :D
        $("#id").val(ui.item.value); 

        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Teste preenchendo : rio ou sao

Eu gosto muito de utilizar jQuery nas minhas aplicações, facilita muito até mesmo o entendimento do Javascript !

Espero ter lhe ajudado.

Comment: Muitissimo obrigada!!!

Comment: Pode votar na minha resposta como solução? rsrs obrigado !

Answer (score 0):

Eu sugiro o uso do elemento `<datalist>`.
Ele adiciona o recurso de autocompletar ao input de forma nativa.

A página no w3schools tem um exemplo funcional: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

Exemplo, extraído do link acima:

```html
<label for="browser">Choose your browser from the list:</label>
<input list="browsers" name="browser" id="browser">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Edge">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

No seu caso, o código ficaria assim:

```html
<input type="text" list="cidade" name="texto">
<datalist id="cidade">
    <option>sao paulo</option>
    <option>rio de janeiro</option>
    <option>vitoria</option>
    <option>belem</option>
    <option>recife</option>
    <option>santa luzia</option>
    <option>santa cruz</option>
    <option>santarem</option>
</datalist>
```

Veja que temos aí, ao invés de um `<select>` temos um `<datalist>` que tem o ID configurado como "cidade" e no `<input>` temos o parâmetro `list="cidade"`, que é responsável por referenciar qual o datalist a ser usado.

Edit: só após postar a resposta foi que notei que a questão é de 2016! Mas fica aqui o registro de uma resposta atualizada com outras opções que existem agora.

Comment: Para melhorar a qualidade da resposta, editei para incluir o exemplo diretamente aqui.